# Prolog beginner here

Tags: prolog

`hasAccount(Person,Bank,Amount)` – the Person has an account at the Bank with the balance Amount,

`lives(Person,City)` – the Person lives in the City,

`created(Person,Bank,Month,Year)` – the Person opened an account at the Bank in Month of the Year.

With the predicates above, I want to try few things, say printing a list of names with accounts they have, I tried the following query.

```
?- hasAccount(Someone, Bank1, Balance1), hasAccount(Someone, Bank2, Balance2), not Bank1 = Bank2.

Someone = ann

Bank1 = metro_credit_union

Balance1 = 1000

Bank2 = toronto_dominion

Balance2 = 12000

Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 1, maybe more)

Someone = ann

Bank1 = toronto_dominion

Balance1 = 12000

Bank2 = metro_credit_union

Balance2 = 1000
```

Can you please explain why do I have reversed list again and what I can do to prevent this happening? Thank you!

Comment: Please change the title of this question.

Answer (score 1):

> why I have reversed list again

it happens since you're not stating in your query enough info to break symmetry.
You can use instead

```
?- hasAccount(Someone, Bank1, Balance1), hasAccount(Someone, Bank2, Balance2), Bank1 @< Bank2.
```

or some builtin, like findall/3 (or [bagof](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=bagof/3)/3)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! My class hasn't covered the @< sign. Just conjunction(,) and negation. Is there a way around with what I have learned from so far?